# what is undefined index error in php?

Tags: php, undefined-index

error: "Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\wamp\www\digi\admin\config\setup.php on line 8"

my code is:

```
    <?php
   #setup document
                      //host-username-password-database_name
   $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dynamic');

   if($_GET['page'] == "")
               {$pg = 'home';}
   else
               {$pg = $_GET['page'];}

   include('/functions/sandbox.php');

   include('/functions/template.php');

   $page_title =  get_page_title($db,$pg);
?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic debugging

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: It means there's no `$_GET` value called "page"

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php   Example #7

Comment: Take a look in the Related sidebar `---->`, plenty of similar questions there `:)`.

Comment: @john conde  i don't know about "basic debugging"

Comment: @sammitch this is not duplicate

Comment: @david there is a $_GET value called 'page'

Comment: @halfer thank you. i fixed it using if(empty($_GET['page']))

Comment: @user2832607: You say there is, but the PHP interpreter says there isn't.  I'm more inclined to believe the PHP interpreter.

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate. There are currently over ***THREE THOUSAND QUESTIONS*** on StackOverflow regarding 'Undefined Index' messages. This *exact* same question is asked a dozen times per day, and the answer is always the same. Try using the search box or google next time.

Comment: It means the variable is not declared<br>Declare your variables, for example when you try to append a string to an undefined variable. Or use `isset() / !empty()` to check if they are declared before referencing them.

Answer (score 4):

`$_GET['page']` is not defined. To correctly check if it exists you should use `isset()`:

```
 if(isset($_GET['page'])) {$pg = 'home';} else {$pg = $_GET['page'];}
```

Comment: i fixed it using empty($_GET['page'])